# Traverse Children of Children returned from JQuery XML object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom, tree

I'm trying to traverse a returned XML file with JQuery and AJAX. And I am having the hardest time figuring out how to get the children of children and returning the data. Everything I try doesn't seem to work. So far I can get the correct number of children in the DATASET, but when i get the children of the first child, it's returning 7 children, when there should be 3. Can anyone solve this?

Here's the data

```
<DATASET>
    <ITEM>
        <COLUMN1>A</COLUMN1>
        <COLUMN2>B</COLUMN2>
        <COLUMN3>C</COLUMN3>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <COLUMN1>D</COLUMN1>
        <COLUMN2>E</COLUMN2>
        <COLUMN3>F</COLUMN3>
    </ITEM>
</DATASET>
```

Here's the call

```
function callAJAX(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "testAjaxData.xml",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id : "paramValue"},
        dataType: "xml"
    });

    request.done(function(xml) {
        var myDoc = "";
        var tree = xml.documentElement.childNodes;

        var $kids = $(xml).find("DATASET").children()
        alert($kids.size());

        $kids.each(function(){
            var tagName=this.tagName;
            alert(tagName + " size: " + childNodes.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
                //alert(this.childNodes[i].value)
            }
        });



    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

Eventually I'd like to have it print out like:

```
Row1: column1=[A] column2=[B] column3=[C] 
Row2: column1=[D] column2=[E] column3=[F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes are included in `childNodes` property including whitespaces, so the whitespaces between the children also count.

Since you're using jQuery, you can do:

```
...
$kids.each(function(){
     var tagName=this.tagName;
     var cols = $(this).children();
     alert(tagName + " size: " + cols.length);
     cols.each(function() {
          //alert(this.value)
     });
});
...
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem was not putting the $() around "this" when i originally tried to get the children via jquery!